# Simple JavaScript appendChild not working

Tags: javascript, appendchild

This is a very "standard" piece of JavaScript code (I've seen it on thousands of examples), but it doesn't work for me:

```
<head>
<title>Temp</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function start() {
        var newScript = document.createElement('script');
        newScript.type = "text/javascript";
        newScript.src = "toBeIncluded.js";  // THIS ONE DOES NOT WORK
        document.body.appendChild(newScript);
        // alert(newScript.contentText);
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onload='start()'>
</body>
</html>
```

In fact I don't get any error, and the  tag gets actually appendeded - unfortunately it is completely empty (I check it with the commented alert line). Please consider that the "toBeIncluded.js" file exists, is not empty, and is in the same local directory of this HTML (I'm running everything locally on my PC).

Please help, I've tried lots of possible variations (change directories, include full path, move code to the "body" section, ...) but no success

Comment: Works for me. Does Error Console in your browser show any errors or warnings?

Comment: Use a HTTP traffic analyzer to determine whether or not a HTTP request for the script file was made (and what the response is).

Comment: No error at all in the Error Console. The DOCTYPE line is: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: I will give a try with a HTTP traffic analyzer, but I don't think I have ever used one before. What tool(s) do you suggest?

Comment: @Bob I use HttpFox - it's a Firefox plug-in. Also, I believe Firebug has one built-in...

Comment: @Sime Thanks for the suggestion. Just downloaded and installed ... result: there is no HMTL activity at all, everything stays blank! What could be the reason?

Comment: @Sime, yes using HttpFox. I am running Firefox 4 beta, but it doesn't work on IE8 as well

Comment: @Bob You have to press the Start button in HttpFox, and **then** you have to load your page and run the JavaScript code. HttpFox should show the request for the HTML page, but also all other requests.

Comment: @Bob ... unless your page is on your local machine. In this case you will have to place it inside your local web-server (if you have one, I use IIS), or upload the page onto your web hosting account.

Comment: @Sime - I did press the start button. Actually I am running everything locally, so I guess this explains why HTTPFox does not work. Later or tomorrow I will try with an external server and I'll post the result. Thanks

Comment: @Sime: some update: I uploaded the two files on a web server and tried again, using HTTPFox. This time, although I still don't get anything, I can "see" in HTTPFow a GET line with the file I am loading dinamically. The file content shows up correctly in the "Content" tab. "Result" was = "(Cache)" the first time, and 304 upon refreshing. Can you help in understanding these results?

Comment: Another question: is the instruction "script.textContent" the right one to visualize the text within the script tags? As I understand, a script tag usually has a child node of type text ... can you confirm that?

Comment: @Bob You get nothing? Isn't that GET line something? How many HTTP requests are logged?

Comment: @Bob Yes, textContent is the right property. Although I don't know whether or not it works for scripts.

Comment: @Sime: well, now it seems that things are working. The problem is: I still don't know what was wrong because, I swear, I didn't change anything ...! However, the textContent property is still not working well in my case, may be is just a timing problem (i.e., script not yet loaded when executing the property), but the script itself gets loaded and executed (I checked with some alerts). Thank a lot for your help

Comment: @Bob Btw, in modern browsers, you can see what scripts got loaded if you open the developer tools. In Chrome, press CTRL + SHIFT + I, then click on the Scripts icon on the top, and then open the drop-down list below those icons - this will show you all scripts that are associated with the current page. If your script has been successfully loaded, it will be in this list.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend installing the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) extension for Firefox. There is also a [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) script for use in other browsers. They work in different ways but have similar features. As others have mentioned, you may benefit from viewing HTTP transaction information. In Firebug this is available in the "Net" panel. If the browser attempts to load the script, then you should see an item in the Net panel. (Make sure you have "All" or "Script" selected in the Net panel options).

If you see the script request listed, then the outcome of the request should also be listed. If it is "404 Not Found", for example, then the URL did not resolve properly. If it is "200 OK" or "304 Not Modified", then the request was successful. If the item shows a small spinner graphic, then it is still trying to connect to the target server.

If the Net panel indicates that the request was successful, then go to the "HTML" panel. The HTML panel shows you the current state of the document object, so if your start function executed properly, then you'll see a "script" element as a child of the body element.

If the script element is successfully added but no HTTP request is made, then you may have a problem with browser security settings. For example, if the request crosses the boundary of HTTP/HTTPS or http/file protocols, the browser may silently decline it.

Try opening a new browser window and requesting the script URL directly. This should help to rule out a misspelled URL or server connection issues.

Comment: @infist - thank for your suggestions. I used to have Firebug, but it is not compatible with the 4.0b.11 beta release that I am using at the moment. Possibly tomorrow I will reinstall the previouos version and test it with Firebug. At the moment I'm doing some check with HTTPFox